# Best practice for integrating clerk with supabase

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, clerk

I came up with my custom react hook for handling supabase, I don't know if using this hook everywhere would be the best practice as I have to deal with `isLoading` every time when I use it.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useAuth } from '@clerk/nextjs'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import { SupabaseClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const createSupabaseClient = (token: string) => {
  if (!process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL) {
    throw new Error('NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL is not defined')
  }
  if (!process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY) {
    throw new Error('NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY is not defined')
  }

  return createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY,
    {
      global: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      },
    },
  )
}

export const useSupabase = () => {
  const { getToken } = useAuth()
  const [supabase, setSupabase] = useState<SupabaseClient>()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTokenAndInitializeClient = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getToken({ template: 'supabase' })
        if (!token) {
          throw new Error('No token found')
        }
        const supabase = createSupabaseClient(token)
        setSupabase(supabase)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err as any)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }

    fetchTokenAndInitializeClient()
  }, [getToken])

  return { supabase, loading, error }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this approach is every time you call `useSupabase` that `useEffect` will run, because the lifecycle will kick off on every component you put this in.

You're correct that we should be dealing with this somewhere.

A good way to tackle this is to create a Provider with `React.Context`.

```
const SupabaseContext = useContext({
  supabase: undefined,
  loading: false,
  error: undefined
})

export const SupabaseProvider({ children }) {
  const { getToken } = useAuth()

  const [supabase, setSupabase] = useState<SupabaseClient>()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTokenAndInitializeClient = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getToken({ template: 'supabase' })
        if (!token) {
          throw new Error('No token found')
        }
        const supabase = createSupabaseClient(token)
        setSupabase(supabase)
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err as any)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }

    fetchTokenAndInitializeClient()
  }, [getToken])

  return (
    <SupabaseContext.Provider value={{ supabase, loading, error }}>
      {children}
    </SupabaseContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Now you can wrap this around the top level of your application like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <SupabaseProvider>
    ...
  </SupabaseProvider>
)
```

And in your components lower down you can access `supabase` (and it's loading and error states) by using a hook:

```
const { supabase, loading, error } = useContext(SupabaseContext);
```

If you don't want to worry about the `loading` state in all your children components, you can use a guard statement higher up in your application to only render children component if `loading` is false.

Here's an example of doing it at the top level in your `SupabaseProvider`:

```
return (
  <SupabaseContext.Provider value={{ supabase, loading, error }}>
    {isloading ? <LoadingSupabase /> : children}
  </SupabaseContext.Provider>
)
```

Comment: What would you recommend for refreshing the clerk token?

Comment: You'd just need to update the `useEffect` logic. I think in the end you would want to store the client in the provider's state and initialize the client on component mount (assuming the token exists), then in a seperate useEffect that listens for token changes, update the existing client (in state) there.